# Inspect Element Shows Wrong result

Tags: html

I have written the following `html` document, as part of a website I'm trying to make:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table>
                <tr id="header">
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                </tr><tr id="body">
                    <td id="left">
                        <h1>Left</h1>
                    </td><td id="center">
                        <h1>Center</h1>
                    </td><td id="right">
                        <h1>Right</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr id="footer">
                    <h1>Footer</h1>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is all well and good, until I open it in browser, at which point I am shown a page setup as follows (according to "Inspect Element"):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Header</h1>
            <h1>Footer</h1>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="body">
                        <td id="left">
                            <h1>Left</h1>
                        </td><td id="center">
                            <h1>Center</h1>
                        </td><td id="right">
                            <h1>Right</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This is, of course, throwing off the effect of my stylesheet, add the appropriate values for `"#header" & "#footer"` are not being applied respectively.

**Questions:**

1. Why is the code the browser is giving me different from the code I wrote?
2. How can I prevent whatever is going on from going on?

Comment: Like this? [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanhvdv/r35pn6as/)

Comment: Are you certain that you are not looking an old cached version of the page?  Try clearing your browser's cache and then reload.

Comment: I'm certain. My html document never looked like that at any point during its composure.

Comment: An `<h1>` cannot be used as a direct child of `<tr>`. **You need a `<th>` or `<td>` in there.** (Likely just a `<th>` instead of an `<h1>`.)

Comment: @Khanhvdv Yes, except my css style sheet should be making it look different (although it's not, due to the absence of the "id" attributes)

Comment: I just opened his HTML in Chrome and it really did remove the `<h1>` tags from the table.

Comment: Usually if the browser gives you something different than your original HTML, it's trying to parse invalid markup...in this case your <h1> being directly in a <tr>.  When HTML doesn't follow the standards, it's anyone's guess how any given browser will handle it...this is a pretty extreme example, but not totally surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose our "Header" in "td".
Below code can help:

```html
        <table>
           <thead>
               <tr> <td colspan="3"> Header  </td>  </tr>  
           </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr id="body">
                <td id="left">
                    <h1>Left</h1>
                </td><td id="center">
                    <h1>Center</h1>
                </td><td id="right">
                    <h1>Right</h1>
                </td>
             
            </tr>
            <tr id="footer">
                <td colspan="3">  <h1>Footer</h1> </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using html min by any chance? Try to include a thead & tbody and that should sort out your problem

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><h1>Header</h1></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h1>Left</h1></td>
      <td><h1>center</h1></td>
      <td><h1>right</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><h1>footer</h1></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```